# Read git changed files with nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, pull

I'm new with nodeJS and have to create a scheduler to list the files that have been changed in a git pull. 
My question is: Which module/lib/way is better for this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a specific module or library are considered "off-topic" for stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the child process module that's built in with Node.js: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

With that you can execute a Git command and parse the output yourself.